# Use global module in node

Tags: node.js

I have a node application with some modules.
I would like to use one of my module in this way:

- Init the module inside server.js (the first file called from npm)
- When the request is passed from socket set the request configuration inside my module
- Use the module with the request configuration in other modules.

Example:

module.js

```
'use strict';

const Module = require('module');

let module = new Module({
    some_information
});

function test(message) {
    module.info(message);
}

function configureRequest(request) {
    module.configure({
        payload: {
            request: request
        }
    });
}

module.exports = {
    info,
    configureRequest
};
```

server.js (little piece of code)

```
let module = require('./src/module.js');
```

get_request.js

```
let module = require('./src/logger.js');
let another = require('./src/another.js');

scServer.on('connection', function (socket) {
     module.configureRequest(socket.request);
     module.info('test'); //inside it there is request 
     another.start();
});
```

another.js

```
let module = require('./src/logger.js');   
module.info('test'); //inside it there isn't request
```

As you can see inside another.js I require again my global module so the request is not set, I don't want if is possible to pass every time the request into all modules (I have many and many modules that use the global module)

How can I solve?

Comment: the link shows How to create a global module for Node.js properly https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/393/how-to-create-a-global-module-for-node-js-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is use consign module to autoload my modules inside my app. https://github.com/jarradseers/consign

Comment: I prefer to don't use a solution like this and understand how to make a global module or how to share it between modules